# PHP -- Getting the time in the subject line

Tags: php, email

I am getting data through Second Life to a PHP script and the PHP script is sending the data through an email.

My question is how to get the time (which is the variable $time) into the subject line of the email. Right now, it is just ignoring the variable $time.

Here is that part of my code:

```
$time = $_POST["time"];
$log = $_POST["log"];

$to = "OSU@gmail.com";
$subject =  <<<TEST
New Visitor; VDC2; $time
TEST;

$theMes =  <<<TEST
Visitor Log for VDC2:
$log
TEST;

$headers = 'From: TecEdgeDL@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
'Message-Id: TecEdgeDL@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: TecEdgeDL@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $theMes, $headers);
```

Comment: What do you mean it's "ignoring the variable $time"? Are you sure that `$time` is not null/empty?

Comment: You can check that with `string.isNullOrEmpty($time);`

Comment: maybe you are not sending the data by POST? try $_GET['time'] (or $_REQUEST)

Comment: @BrianDriscoll: Yes I am sure it's not empty I echo'ed out $time in other parts of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you write the $subject variable like this instead?

```
$subject = "New Visitor; VDC2; " . $time;
```

And while you're at it, write $theMes like this:

```
$theMes = "Visitor Log for VDC2:" . "\n\n" . 
   $log;
```

---

If that doesn't work try encoding the content.  I still don't know why it wouldn't display but this might be worth a shot since mail does encode.

```
$subject = "New Visitor; VDC2; " . $time;
$subject = '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=';
```

There could be something with the semicolons or timestamp that's confusing PHP.

Comment: And as noted, make sure the "time" value is retrieved of course - assumed you've done that already.

Comment: I only wrote it like I did because it wasn't getting the variables correctly from Second Life. The way I wrote it works for some reason.. I'm not a PHP guy. Also, yes the $time variable is being retrieved.

Comment: try it how recommended and report please as it should work if time value is retrieved.  another way to do the same thing would be $subject = sprintf("New Visitor; VDC2; %s", $time); as well

Comment: One reason you may not want to change $theMes is if the log value has a lot of text, you may already be handling the new line wrapping which is 70 chars max per line so perhaps only change $subject for now.  You can use wordwrap(...) for message if you run into that issue.

Comment: I tried both of your $subject lines and both are still not printing out $time but does print everything else. Is there a way to just get the time of the email being sent so you don't have to worry about Second Life?

Comment: see addition content in answer and add that 2nd line and try.

Comment: if you don't want Second Life time, create your own in PHP:
$time = date("H:i:s");

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much Mike I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: my pleasure and can you specify what exactly worked perfectly?  the PHP time or the encoding suggestion (or both) for others benefit.

Comment: the encoding.. I did not try the PHP time but I assume that should have worked as well. Thanks again.